# How to write a test with Vue3 Testing Library after change computed method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3

I have tried to write the test for Vue3 component with testing-library/vue 
 I have a span element and it changes after change computed method. How I can check the value in the span element after execution computed method. 
 Method computed depens on variable from store Pinia

MyComponent :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="ml-10 w-full">
      <span class="text-3xl mb-2.5" role="span">{{ song_name }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">
import { useSongStore } from '@/stores/songs'
import { computed } from 'vue'

const songsStore = useSongStore()

const random_obj_song = computed(() => {
  return songsStore.random_obj_song
})

let song_name = computed(() => {
  return songsStore.isGas ? random_obj_song.value?.name : '******'
})
</script>
```

```
test.spec.ts

describe('ThePlayer', () => {
  const renderThePlayer = () => {
    const pinia = createTestingPinia();
    const store = useSongStore()

    render(ThePlayer, {
      global: {
        plugins: [pinia]
      }
    })

    return { store }
  }

  it.only('display the name of song', async ()=> {
    const {  store} = renderThePlayer();
    const spanEl = screen.getByRole('span');
    store.isGas = true;
    expect(spanEl.textContent).not.toBe('******')
  });
})
```

Comment: What did you try? You can make songsStore.isGas fulfill the requirement depending how the store works or mock the store

Comment: @EstusFlask, I added my test, you can see it. The problem, that when I change store property store.isGas = true, the computed property doen't recompile and the text in span stays the same '******'

Comment: What is isGas, is it store state and not a getter? The changes may not immediate, rely on testing-library api for selectors, e.g. `await findByText(...), or `await nextTick()` for more generic approach

Comment: @EstusFlask, Thank you so much,  await nextTick() it helps me!